# Is this "Dear Liberal Communists" poster a real poster from Turning Point USA?

Tags: united-states, politics

The following poster has circulated on social media and blogs:

[image: An image of political candidate Sery Kim, with the quote 'Dear liberal communists how can I be racist if I am Korean']

Examples:

- https://twitter.com/viet_t_nguyen/status/1378598473314930691
- https://twitter.com/krupali/status/1378556380550852613
- https://www.tiktok.com/@edfromwales/video/6947932435023809797
- https://old.reddit.com/r/aznidentity/comments/mp8aln/boba_conservatives_be_like/
- https://www.joemygod.com/2021/04/gop-house-candidate-sues-texas-paper-for-branding-her-racist-over-comments-about-chinese-immigrants/

**Was this poster actually made by Turning Point USA?**

Comment: Welcome to  Skeptics, we invite you to take our [tour] and refer to the [help] to help get your bearings. Enjoy the site.

Comment: I've sent an email to TurningPointsUSA to have them either confirm or deny the meme/image.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance it looks like a [Turning Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_Point_USA) meme. Some examples are of [Ben Shapiro](https://www.google.com/search?q=ben%20shapiro%20turning%20point%20meme&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi21rTkiI7xAhWKlJ4KHf3uAXwQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=ben%20shapiro%20turning%20point%20meme&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1AAWABgwC5oAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=_IvCYLboPIqp-gT93YfgBw&bih=764&biw=1536) and [Jordan Peterson](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jordan%20B%20Peterson%20turning%20point%20meme&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjmq868iI7xAhU-LDQIHahGBP4Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Jordan%20B%20Peterson%20turning%20point%20meme&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1AAWABg0i1oAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=qYvCYKazIL7Y0PEPqI2R8A8&bih=764&biw=1536).

This meme format is quite popular "on the left", and is used to mock or poke fun at conservative viewpoints. It's quite difficult to explain without bias, however, there is a [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ToiletPaperUSA/) that shows these photoshops aren't just a one-off thing.

As for Sery, to the best of my ability this is what I could find as to the original picture.

[image: Sery Kim, Republican for Tx-06 // Small businesses: grow, baby, grow // Immigration: legal—yes. Illegal—no way. // 2nd amendment: hell, yeah // covid: shots in arms and back to business // veterans and their families come first // values: praise Jesus // Learn more at seryfortexas.com]

Comment: When and where did it first appear? (Both versions preferably). Then there's [this one](http://img.yna.co.kr/etc/inner/KR/2021/03/12/AKR20210312009000075_02_i.jpg) 11th March 2021, which came first?

Comment: For clarity: it's a meme based on the actual statement that she made at the end of March 2021. https://www.texastribune.org/2021/04/03/sery-kim-texas/

Comment: 30th of March on her [twitter](https://twitter.com/seryfortexas/status/1376891444477169666?lang=en). Not sure what article A Rouge Ant was talking about as his comment only links to the homepage, so I cant say for certain what the true date of the original ad came from. The first new reports about the remarks from Sery were published on April 1st, first so the meme obviously comes after that date.

Comment: @CarlosMedina It seems that Korea Daily is leery about searches of their archives from my IP address, but [Tin Eye](https://tineye.com/search) provided me the link, your results may vary.

Comment: I can't tell from your google image links what's a "turning point meme" and what's not. What even is "Turning Point"?

Comment: @fredsbend Sorry I couldn't help you understand, I'm not sure how to create a gallery of a lot of similar images that ideally showcases what I mean, and the subreddit I linked to has many other memes besides the one I wanted to showcase. But, Turning Point USA is a conservative organization that, among other things, makes posters espousing conservative viewpoints. These were seen as cliché by people on the left on the internet which led to Photoshop of posters around 2017 (TPUSA subreddit founded in October 2017).

Comment: @fredsbend For more information on Turning point you can look at [this web page](https://www.desmog.com/turning-point-usa/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYAYFgmOWAI&t=4m43s).